# From validation Throws error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

i am new to laravel..Kind of stuck at this place. Tried many solutions for this but none worked yet, There are similar question but most unresolved, or proper evident solution not posted yet(from google,stackoverflow ..etc)

i have defned a custom route

```
Route::post('/ComplaintGenerate', 'ComplaintsController@generate');
```

whenever i submit the view with 'POST' method as

```
<form action="/ComplaintGenerate" method="POST" >
```

without any validation rule in my Complaintscontroller everything works fine and i can save data. but when i put validation either through Requests or direct it throws error **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

if i remove validation everything works fine. I also tried with GET method but still dint work.
A little peace of advice will be very much appreciated.

Web.route

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
Route::post('/Complaint', 'ComplaintsController@find'); 
Route::post('/ComplaintGenerate', 'ComplaintsController@generate');
Route::post('/Complaint/{Complaint}', 'ComplaintsController@save_customer');
Route::resource('Complaints', 'ComplaintsController');
Route::resource('Occupancies', 'OccupanciesController');
Route::resource('Customers', 'CustomersController');
Route::resource('Services', 'ServiceController');
Route::resource('ServiceTeams', 'ServiceTeamController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');});
```

My controller:

```
public function generate(GenerateInitialComplaintRequest $request)
{  
    $complaint = Complaint::find($request->complaint_id);
    $complaint->update([
        'complaint_date'=>$request->complaint_date,
        'complaint_description'=>$request->complaint_description,   
    ]);

    return redirect(route('Complaints.index')->with('complaint', Complaint::all()));           
}
```

my View:

```
<div class="container my-5">

<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center my-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">

            <form action="/ComplaintGenerate" method="POST" >
          @csrf
          @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="complaint_id">Complaint Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complaint_id" name="complaint_id" value="{{$complaint->id}}" readonly >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="complaint_date">Complaint Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complaint_date" name="complaint_date">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
              <label for="complaint_description">Complaint Description</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="complaint_description" name="complaint_description" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>             
         <div class="text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                
         </div>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When it throw error, check the url in browser.

Comment: And show that url in question

Comment: url remains as that of previous route when i check for form validation http://127.0.0.1:8000/Complaint/2 with above error , and when i fill all the details i get http://127.0.0.1:8000/ComplaintGenerate

Comment: According to your route that you provided in question:Route::post('/Complaint/{Complaint}', 'ComplaintsController@save_customer');

Comment: It is post request. Laravel goes on this route. So that is why you get error.

Comment: if i change route of ComplaintsController@save_customer to GET , i get  "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD." error

Comment: Wow, You are correct , Thanks alot ..It worked

Answer (score 0):

What is the route for displaying your form? When validation fails, Laravel makes redirection using GET method to the route it was displayed from.

I assume the form might be displayed in the `find` method of your `ComplaintsController`, and when validation fails, there's redirection to this route and that is what throws an error.

Can you also show your validation methods and what data are you trying to send through form?

Comment: The route for displaying form is through              
 Route::post('/Complaint/{Complaint}', 'ComplaintsController@save_customer');

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution as mentioned by  Ankur Mishra and Aryal, 
We have to remember as mentioned by Aryal When validation fails, Laravel makes redirection using GET method to the route it was displayed from. And i displayed  my form through below

```
Route::post('/Complaint/{Complaint}', 'ComplaintsController@save_customer');
```

Controller method:

```
public function save_customer($id)
{         
    $complaint = Complaint::create([
        'customer_id'=>$id
    ]);
   // $complaint = Complaint::whereCustomer_id($id)->firstorfail();
    return view('complaints.initial_complaint')->with('complaint', $complaint);            
}
```

'complaints.initial_complaint' is the view which has the form which gave me the error of
**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.** on submission
So i change POST route to GET :-

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
//Route::resource('Complaints', 'ComplaintsController');
Route::get('/Complaint', 'ComplaintsController@find');      
Route::get('/Complaint/{Complaint}', 'ComplaintsController@save_customer');
Route::get('/ComplaintGenerate', 'ComplaintsController@generate');
Route::resource('Complaints', 'ComplaintsController');
Route::resource('Occupancies', 'OccupanciesController');
Route::resource('Customers', 'CustomersController');
Route::resource('Services', 'ServiceController');
Route::resource('ServiceTeams', 'ServiceTeamController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

});

and in view i passed GET as hidden method

```
<form action="/ComplaintGenerate" method="POST" >
          @csrf
          @method('GET')
          @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="complaint_id">Complaint Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complaint_id" name="complaint_id" value="{{$complaint->id}}" readonly >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="complaint_date">Complaint Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complaint_date" name="complaint_date">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
              <label for="complaint_description">Complaint Description</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="complaint_description" name="complaint_description" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>             
         <div class="text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                
         </div>
    </form>
```

and now it is working me.. Just posted so if anybody could use it for future reference

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
Route::get('/ComplaintGenerate', 'ComplaintsController@generate');
Route::post('/ComplaintGenerate', 'ComplaintsController@generate');
```